# Why did just get " nope " ? I want this{ {2, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 2}, {3, 1}}. How can I get that with function "Table"?

Tags: programming

How can I get that with function "Table"? Here are my codes

```
sam[m_, n_] := 
Module[{}, 
 If[m == 1 && EvenQ[n], {m, n + 1}, If[n == 1 && OddQ[m], {m + 1, n},
 If[OddQ[m + n], {m - 1, n + 1}, 
  If[EvenQ[m + n], {m + 1, n - 1}, "nope"]]]]];
 sam[1, 1];
 Table[sam[m, n], {j, 1, 5}]
```

Comment: In your `Table` the arguments to `sam` are not given any values. The iterator for `j` just gives five calls with symbolic arguments which each evaluate to "nope".

Comment: You need to call sam[ ] with two arguments: something like Table[sam[i, j], {j, 1, 3}, {i, 1, 3}]

Comment: @bills   That's not what I want ```{{{2, 1}, {1, 3}, {2, 2}}, {{1, 2}, {3, 1}, {1, 4}}, {{4, 1}, {2, 
   3}, {4, 2}}}```, if you continue this , it will be like this. ```{2, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 2}, {3, 1}, {4, 1}, {3, 2}, {2, 3}, {1, \
4}, {1, 5}```

Comment: kile, j is not in your function and you are just calling sam with two unassigned variables—they have no numerical value. What do you expect that stepping j forward from 1 to 5 will do, when it is not a term in your function? Are you hoping for a 5x5 array of the terms that would be associated with the corresponding position indices of the array?

Comment: @CATrevillian ```sam[{m_, n_}] := 
  Module[{}, 
   If[m == 1 && EvenQ[n], {m, n + 1}, If[n == 1 && OddQ[m], {m + 1, n},
     If[OddQ[m + n], {m - 1, n + 1}, 
      If[EvenQ[m + n], {m + 1, n - 1}, "nope"]]]]];  NestList[sam, {1, 1}, 10]``` That's the code I get it right. But I want get it done with Table function

Comment: Why `Table` specifically? Is it that you want an array of values at the end with a nested structure?

Answer (score 1):

I am sure I am overthinking this, but here's an answer. Put the `{ }` into your function call.

```
sam[{m_, n_}] := Module[{},

   If[m == 1 && EvenQ[n], {m, n + 1},
    If[n == 1 && OddQ[m], {m + 1, n},
     If[OddQ[m + n], {m - 1, n + 1},
      If[EvenQ[m + n], {m + 1, n - 1},
       "nope"]
      ]
     ]
    ]
   ];
```

Now generate the data, which will be a 2D table

```
dat = Partition[Flatten@Table[{i, j}, {i, 3}, {j, 3}], 2];
(* {{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 1}, {2, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 1}, {3, 2}, {3, 3}} *)
```

Map your function over it, then sort it by `Total` but write as `{Total}` in order to ensure a stable sort. Voila!

```
SortBy[Map[sam, dat], {Total}]
(* {{2, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 2}, {3, 1}, {1, 4}, {4, 1}, {2, 3}, {4, 2}} *)
```

Comment: That's not right, it should be ```{{2, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 2}, {3, 1}, {4, 1}, {3, 2}, {2, 3}, {1, 
  4}, {1, 5}}``` when {j, 1, 10} is set this